# vba byref argument reference not available

Tags: vba, excel

Given that the called procedure actually sets the passed Range object ByRef, I am expecting the object reference to be available in the calling procedure. But it is still Nothing.

What is the fix?

**calling**

```
Private Sub Specs_TryGetRangeFromDefinedName_CanFindGlobalName()

Dim Specs As New SpecSuite
Dim rngResult As Excel.range
Dim bResult As Boolean

bResult = TryGetRangeFromDefinedName(rngResult, "LongTermTaxRate", ThisWorkbook.Name)
With Specs.It("should return refersTo range when the name is global")
    .Expect(bResult).ToEqual True
    .Expect(rngResult.address).ToEqual "$B$2" ** FAIL (object is Nothing)2
End With

SpecRunner.RunSuite Specs

End Sub
```

**called**

```
Public Function TryGetRangeFromDefinedName(ByRef aRange As Excel.range, _
                                       ByRef aName As String, _
                                       ByRef aWkbName As String, _
                              Optional ByRef aSheetName As String = vbNullString) As Boolean

Dim rngResult As Excel.range

If IsValued(aName) And IsValued(aWkbName) Then
    On Error Resume Next
    If IsValued(aSheetName) Then
        ' local name (presumably)
        Set rngResult = Workbooks(aWkbName).Worksheets(aSheetName).range(aName)
    Else
        ' global name (presumably)
        Set rngResult = Workbooks(aWkbName).Names(aName).RefersToRange
    End If
    TryGetRangeFromDefinedName = (err.Number = 0)
    On Error GoTo 0
End If

End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Parameter `aRange` is never used, and `rngResult` is assigned but never referenced. Get rid of `rngResult` and assign `aRange` instead.

Also, the intent of your method would be clearer if the `String` parameters were passed `ByVal`, since they're not assigned.

---

<sub>These observations are all [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduck-vba.com) code inspections results (disclaimer: I co-own this project).</sub>

Comment: I *knew* it was something incredibly stupid. Thanks :)